# Which method is preferable in terms of performance while adding strings to List/Map?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

String or String Builder which one is preferable in the below method ? Kindly explain.

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList< String >();
    list.add(new String ("One"));
    list.add(new String ("Two"));
    list.add(new String ("Three"));
    .
    .
    .
    list.add(new String ("N"));
```

(or)

```
ArrayList<StringBuilder> list=new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    list.add(new StringBuilder("One"));
    list.add(new StringBuilder("Two"));
    list.add(new StringBuilder("Three"));
    .
    .
    .
    list.add(new StringBuilder("N"));
```

Comment: `list.add(“One”);` is preferable

Comment: Or `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", ... "N"));`.

Comment: `in terms of performance..` - so the first approach creates a String Object. The second approach creates a String object and a StringBuilder object. Which do you think is preferable and why?

Comment: There is hardly ever any reason to use the constructor `new String` - `String` is immutable, even the [JavaDocs explicitly mention:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) "Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable."

Comment: Neither. You're achieving two different goals as you're constructing lists designated to hold different types of objects.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on google search not a own answer, I think my small effort help you in better understanding of the topic.

**Stringbuilder vs string:**

> - String is immutable whereas StringBuffer and StringBuider are mutable    classes.
> - StringBuffer is thread safe and synchronized whereas StringBuilder is    not, thats why StringBuilder is more faster than StringBuffer.
> - String concat + operator internally uses StringBuffer or    StringBuilder class.

[Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

**Conclusion/Answer:**

Everyone prefer stringbuilder compare to string

Answer (score 0):

This is depend on your requirement, if you want to modify object located at certain index then go for string builder. But again if you are working in a multithreaded environment then you have to use string builder carefully as it is a mutable class.

If you are not modifying your list then you must go for String.